# How To: Change application name based on phone language setting

Tags: windows-phone-7, localization, globalization

I have noticed that when i change phone settings, that some of the applications on the phone change their name based on selected language.

eg. Where you change phone settings is Settings (english), Parametres (french), Configuracion (spanish)

Does anyone know how to do this for my own application?

I can change the strings inside my application.  I want to change the application name that is displayed beside (or overtop) the application tile.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Microsoft [wrote a detailed guide on how](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff967550%28v=vs.92%29.aspx).

And yes, it's a C++ satellite DLL. You're not reading it wrong.

Consider using [Patrick Getzmann's Tool to automate the satellite generation](http://patrickgetzmann.wordpress.com/wp7-localize/)

Comment: hm.. quite interesting problem and article. The article describes how to create a "resource-only" dll. This is important, because it clearly indicates, that in this dll there will be no actual code, just resources - so they are using C++ compiler only for its near-endless configurability to produce modules. This article seems to solve the problem in a normal localisation-by-satellites way. I think that we could easily force the VisualStudio to generate the proper satellits just with a (single?) handcrafted RESX file. If I find a 2-3 hrs for the experiment,I'll post the results as an answer.

Comment: I've done it before (manually) for two languages (English and Danish). But iirc there's already a tool to automate it, let me see if I can find the link.

Comment: And a lesson I learned the hard way - ***DO NOT*** rename the DLLs or even place them in a sub-folder of the XAP. Or your app gets rejected during submission.